# return result from function and use results in another function php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is code for fileupload,

What i want is that function return file path and then file path, i need to use in sendemail function,

```
public function add_attachments($ticket_id)
{
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/attach/'.$attach_id;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|doc|pdf';
            $config['max_size']    = '1024000000';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            }
            else
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $file_name = $data['file_name'];
            }
          return $file_name;
            //echo base_url().'uploads/attach/' .$file_name;

}
```

Now above function will return in $file_name,
I want this to be use in same value in another function, example send_email()

This two function will be executed simultaneously by Jquery in HTML, means upload attachments and send email with attachments.

Here are Jquery components,

Function to upload and submit,

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
paramName : 'userfile',
autoProcessQueue: false,
//maxFilesize : 0.1,
url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/upload/add_attachments/"+<?php echo $attach->attach_id; ?>,
init: function() {

    var myDropzone = this;

     // Here's the change from enyo's tutorial...

        $("#ticketreply_fm").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            sendreply();
            }
        );
```

sendreply() function will send additional data with AJAX return,

Thanks advanced,

Comment: Do you tried call that `second function` before `return $file_name;`?

Comment: just on return of file name , check for its existence by using empty, and send mail based on the result.

Comment: @gmo, i can not do that, as sendreply() function jquery pointing to sendmail() php function with AJAX and sendmail() function should get file_name from add_attachment() function

Comment: Ok, I see.. so if I understood correctly, the `sendreply() is a javascript funcion` and should contain the `php $file_name var` to pass it over to `sendmail() function` that it's also in javascript, Is that right? If it's, share your `ajax function` because it's there where you have to pass over the value. If not.. please explain the hole process and relative function so we can make a better idea.

Comment: @gmo, sendreply() is JS function and does not contain any variable, just a ajax call to PHP sendmail() function. but if you see above JS code, i had called sendreply() in another JS function, means first add_attachment() PHP will run, it should return $file_name and same $file_name access by another PHP function sendmail(). So in PHP two function will run.

Comment: I don't see where you call the `PHP add_attachments()` function. Is that called by another ajax from `myDropzone.processQueue();` ??

Comment: @gmo, Yes add_attachment is called by dropzone submit, see updated code

Comment: Worth mentioning that you use `dropzone` ;).. le me post as an answer so I can share some code for you to test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get you clearly but if I what I'm thinking is your problem, then

1. Set a private property called `private $file_name;`
2. Then in the add attachment method use this:

   ```
   public function add_attachments($ticket_id) {
       $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/attach/'.$attach_id;
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|doc|pdf';
       $config['max_size']    = '1024000000';

       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
       {
           $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
       }
       else
       {
           $data = $this->upload->data();
           $this->file_name = $data['file_name'];
       }
     return $this->file_name;
       //echo base_url().'uploads/attach/' .$file_name;
   ```

}

3. Create a public method to get the file name like

   ```
   public function get_file_name() {
      return $this->file_name;
   }
   ```
4. So you can now have the value of the file name using the `get_file_name()` method.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dropzone Docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-queuecomplete)...   There's an event called: `queuecomplete` that can be invoque to trigger the second function you need...
Something like:

```
// use this to get the attr you need, like the name.
myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  console.log("file", file);
  console.log("xhr", xhr);
  console.log("formData", formData);
});
```

So would be something like:

```
$("#ticketreply_fm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    myDropzone.processQueue();
    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file, xhr, formData) {
        // make the call here to sendmail() function with `$file.name` var...
        sendreply();
    });
});
```

*I never use `Dropzone` before.. so I'm only guessing based on the doc.

Hope it helps*

Comment: thanks for this but my problem is in PHP side, where i want output of add_attachment() function to be use in another sendmail() function, because file will be uploaded in server and i want that filename+path to attach in email.

Comment: Yeap... that was clear, but you said you cannot call `sendmail()` in `add_attachment()` ... then.. you need to catch the file_name and make another ajax call to php with that var as parameter... Or... don't call `add_attachment()` directly... call another function and include both request there..